# Bloc Listener not working after phone is locked and then unlocked

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Bloc listener isn't working on the view section once the device is locked and unlocked even though the bloc events are handled inside the bloc and is being emitted.
The bloc is being provided as an inherited widget to the root of the application which is getting reset after device is locked -> unlocked.

In main

```
OrderBlocProvider(
                child: MaterialApp(
```

Inherited widget

```
class OrderBlocProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final OrderBloc orderBloc;
  OrderBlocProvider({Key? key, Widget? child})
      : orderBloc = OrderBloc(), super(key: key, child: child!);

  bool updateShouldNotify(_) => true;

  static OrderBloc? of(BuildContext context) {
    return context
        .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<OrderBlocProvider>()
        ?.orderBloc;
  }
}
```

It is accessed as

```
    _orderBloc = OrderBlocProvider.of(context) as OrderBloc;
```

Events are being received on the view inside the build method

```
BlocListener<OrderBloc, OrderState>(listener: (context, state) {
```

> UPDATE

I was able to resolve this by adding the provider to the builder method of the MaterialApp but now `BlocListener` is being called multiple times whenever the route is being called.

```
MaterialApp(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                    return Provider<OrderBloc>(
                      create: (_) => _orderBloc,
                      child: MediaQuery(
                        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                          textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                        ),
                        child: child!,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

> UPDATE 2

Finally it worked after replacing BlocListener with `StreamSubscription sub` and then cancelling it on the dispose of the widget.

Comment: How is the bloc provided to the widget tree? Can you show us the code calling it?

Comment: @VincentDR added the code blocks

Comment: and where are the bloc events received (or not in your case)?

Comment: @VincentDR updated the code. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: If there is no error displayed anywhere, can you check that the orderBloc = OrderBloc() is not called several times, and maybe the widget does not reference the right bloc. It's hard to tell without the full widget code creating/using the bloc